# Where can I find accident statistics on zero gravity flights?

Tags: airline-operations, accidents, airlines, accident-statistics

I am investigating the option of booking a zero gravity flight with a commercial airline. But I am a nervous flyer.

Do any of the airlines offering this have a 0% accident / fatality record?

Comment: All of them, none have had accidents.

Comment: As with every flight the most dangerous part is driving to the airport... ;o)

Comment: If you are a nervous flyer then the vomit comet is not for you @Cloud.

Comment: What @GdD said:  If you are a self-identified nervous flyer, why in the world would you want a zero-G flight?  Perhaps a nervous flyer would be better suited to a flight school Intro Flight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reduced gravity flight is just as a normal flight but doing some stuff at a high altitude, typically between 24,000 and 32,000 feet. The stuff they do is this:

[image: Parabola]
*<sub>[Image Source](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/6056495/ns/technology_and_science-space/t/are-zero-gravity-flights-safe/)</sub>*

Regarding the safety, [FAA spokesman](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/6056495/ns/technology_and_science-space/t/are-zero-gravity-flights-safe/) said:

> Asked whether these parabolic flights will be as safe as normal
>   commercial flights, [FAA spokesman], “If they operate within the
>   parameters that we set out, yes, they will be safe.”

There have not been any accidents occurred for a commercial reduced gravity flight.

Comment: How is 34k feet zero gravity? Isn't that normal altitude?

Comment: @Cloud The "Zero-G" comes from the parabolic maneuver the aircraft is performing, not the altitude.

Comment: While the manoeuvres are different from normal airline operations, they are (probably) well briefed, (probably) flown by well-experienced pilots, and (if flown correctly) well within the approved capabilities of the aeroplane. That would make them, at the very least, not unsafe per se.

Comment: @Cloud:  So far from your comments, it seems that you are a nervous flyer, and don't even really know what a Zero-G flight is or how it works.  You even say you're wary of booking one.  Simple answer: Don't.  This experience is not for you until you understand it better and are comfortable with it.  There is a high probability you'll have a panic attack, or get violently sick, and spoil the experience for other passengers while having a horrible time yourself.  Please reconsider.

Comment: @Cloud just to clarify for you if you are not certain: the actual "zero G" part lasts only a very short time.  (30 seconds?)  The whole flight is only for the purpose of that short moment.   Surely you have been on a rollercoaster where you feel "light" as you go over the top?  That's all it is, they just do that, and make it last (say) 30 seconds.  Enjoy!